# all error message working in postman but not in display frontend client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postman

I am creating a website using react and node .in my server register and login all message working in postman properly but in display side the register error showing properly but my login error is not showing (Ex: user doesn't exist, username or password incorrect)

I need to display error not valid password like in my website.but the errormessage not showing in display after catch think in login page.
router login

```js
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { identifier, password } = req.body;
  console.log("Login request:", identifier, password); // Log the request parameters

  const user = await UserModel.findOne({
    $or: [{ username: identifier }, { email: identifier }],
  });
  console.log("User found:", user); // Log the retrieved user

  if (!user) {
    console.log("User not found"); // Log the condition
    return res.json({ message: "User Doesn't Exist!" });
  }

  const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
  console.log("Is password valid:", isPasswordValid); // Log the password comparison result

  if (!isPasswordValid) {
    console.log("Incorrect password"); // Log the condition
    return res.json({ message: "Username or Password is Incorrect" });
  }

  const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, "secret");
  console.log("Login successful. Token:", token); // Log the generated token
  res.json({ token, userID: user._id });
});
```

this is my login page

```js
const Login = () => {
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [identifier, setIdentifier] = useState("");
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");

  const [_, setcookies] = useCookies(["access_token"]);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const onSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/auth/login", {
        identifier,
        password,
      });
      console.log("Login Response:", response.data);

      setcookies("access_token", response.data.token);
      window.localStorage.setItem("userID", response.data.userID);
      navigate("/");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.response.data);
      setErrorMessage(err.response.data.message);
      console.log("Error Message:", err.response.data.message);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="sign-text-content">
      <div className="text-full">
        <div className="text-content">
          <img src="Group1.svg" alt="img" />{" "}
        </div>
        <span className="plan">
          {" "}
          <img src="planGroup20.svg" alt="imgae" />
        </span>
      </div>
      <div className="bluesign"> </div>
      <Form className="register-form" action="" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <span className="welcome">
          {" "}
          <img src="welcome.svg" alt="im" />{" "}
        </span>
        <Form.Group className="form-group" controlId="identifier">
          <Form.Label className="text-uppercase"></Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            value={identifier}
            onChange={(event) => setIdentifier(event.target.value)}
            placeholder="Username or Email"
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="form-group" controlId="password">
          <Form.Label className="text-uppercase"></Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            className="form-control"
            type="password"
            onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
            value={password}
            placeholder="Password"
          />
          {errorMessage && <div className="text-danger">{errorMessage}</div>}
          <Button
            variant="primary"
            type="submit"
            id="btn-log"
            className="btn btn-login float-right"
          >
            Login
          </Button>
        </Form.Group>
        <div className="clearfix"></div>
        <div className="form-group">
          Create new account ? Please <Link to="/auth">Register</Link>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

in my console showing login

Respone:Object
message : "User Doesn't Exist!"

Comment: try to set http status code 404 not found and check if it works or not. `return res.status(404).json({ message: "User Doesn't Exists" });`

Comment: Question is unclear. You state "the register error showing properly but my login error is not showing". It is unclear which errors you are refering to. You should reduce the code to a small, reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the axios HTTP library throws an error anytime the destination server responds with a 4XX / 5XX error.

In your case, the server responds with default success status (200).

So, respond with the appropriate status to throw error in the client side.

```js
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { identifier, password } = req.body;
  console.log("Login request:", identifier, password); // Log the request parameters

  const user = await UserModel.findOne({
    $or: [{ username: identifier }, { email: identifier }],
  });
  console.log("User found:", user); // Log the retrieved user

  if (!user) {
    console.log("User not found"); // Log the condition
    return res.status(404).json({ message: "User Doesn't Exist!" });
  }

  const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
  console.log("Is password valid:", isPasswordValid); // Log the password comparison result

  if (!isPasswordValid) {
    console.log("Incorrect password"); // Log the condition
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "Username or Password is Incorrect" });
  }

  const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, "secret");
  console.log("Login successful. Token:", token); // Log the generated token
  res.json({ token, userID: user._id });
});
```